# Formatting Text at Bookmark after Userform Selection

Tags: vba, ms-word

I apologize if this is a novice question. I have a Word document that has a bookmark placed a certain point. I created a userform that inserts text into the document depending on the selection (checkbox 1 or 2). I can get the text inserted, but I am wondering if the text being inserted at the bookmark can be formatted.

For instance, I'd like the text to be underlined, regardless of selecting checkbox 1 or 2. However, I'd like the text inserted from checkbox 2 to also be bolded.

Below is the code that I have been using. The name of the bookmark is CalSub.

Thanks!

```
Dim strSub As String
If CheckBox1 = True Then strSub = "Notice of Data Security Incident "
If CheckBox2 = True Then strSub = "Notice of Data Breach"

'Clean up formatting

With ActiveDocument
    .Bookmarks("CalSub").Range.Text = strSub
    End With
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Dim rng As Range, doc As Document

Set doc = ActiveDocument
Set rng = doc.Bookmarks("CalSub").Range  'get the range
rng.Text = strSub                        'set the text (note this will delete the bookmark)
doc.Bookmarks.Add "CalSub", rng          'recreate bookmark          
rng.Font.Underline = True                'always underline
If CheckBox2 Then rng.Font.Bold = True   'set bold depending on value of checkbox
```

Comment: Tim, Thank you so much! I just have one follow-up question: the code works in the sense that everything is correctly underlined and bolded, but the text appears next to each other like **Notice of Data Breach**Notice of Data Breach. Do you know what needs to removed to eliminate the duplication?

Comment: I just tested and the text is only inserted once, so I'm not sure how you're getting the duplicated text.

Comment: Your code was absolutely correct. It was because I had accidentally left the With Active Document piece. Thanks again!